I'm trying to use mediapipe.solutions but it doesn't seem to want to show solutions attribute
Unable to install mediapipe via pip install mediapipe resulting in mediapipe.solutions attribute not found.
I'm running on Windows and trying to test a hand gesture using opencv and mediapipe but had trouble installing with pip install mediapipe because it resulted in ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe so I install it via MSYS2. initially I put the repo on C:/Users/User/mediapipe but when I tried calling import mediapipe it results in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediapipe', so I tried putting the repo on the project file and somehow I can call mediapipe. the problem resides in when I call mediapipe.solutions and results in AttributeError: module 'mediapipe' has no attribute 'solutions' I searched it and the problem resides in library name on issue#1928 the solution is on the first problem I found which is to install it with pip, how do I fix this?
Running on Windows, pip 24.0, python 3.12
This is my code:
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import pyautogui
handcap = mp.solutions.hands.Hands()
drawings = mp.solutions.drawing_utlis
def testdevice(source):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(source)
    while True:
        _,image = camera.read()
        image = cv2.flip(image,1)   
        rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        hand_output= handcap.process(rgb_img)
        allhand = hand_output.multi_hand_landmarks
        if allhand:
            for hands in allhand:
                drawings.draw_landmarks(image,hands)
        cv2.imshow("Hand Movement Video Capture",image)
        key = cv2.waitKey(100)
        if key == 27:
            break
    camera.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
testdevice(0)
testdevice(1)


one issue i missed from the beginning, mediapipe is still on experimental stage and only supports python 3.8-3.11.
so the solution was just to reinstall my python to 3.8

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
